# Can i use request with electron? I'm not seeing any events

Tags: node.js, electron

Context: When i'm running electron before compiling everything works correctly

I have a NodeJS module that is leveraging the request wrapper 'request-progress'. When i execute my app pre compile, i'm able to download the asset and store it in the output of app.getDataPath()

I do see output for COM:Downloading ....

When i compile the app, i don't see any output from the event emitters, and i dont see anything in the Chrom Dev tools.

```
function downloadAllIMages(path, filename) {
    log.debug('COM: Downloading ' + path);
    progress(request(path), {
      throttle: 2000,                    // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms
      delay: 1000,                       // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms
      lengthHeader: 'x-transfer-length'  // Length header to use, defaults to content-length
    })
      .on('progress', function (state) {
        log.debug('progress', state);
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        log.debug('err', err);
      })
      .on('end', function () {
        log.debug('event completed');
      })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
  });
```

Are there any restrictions on how a packaged electron can make Htpp requests? Again, works fine pre compilation step running 'electron .'

Comment: I'm using it in a very similar way and it works great even running electron by command line even in a packaged app.

Comment: @Jack Murphy, did you figure this out?  I'm running into this as well.

Comment: For me, using fetch works in development, but when I package the app I get an error saying "url is not defined". I'm not entirely sure if that error and your issue are related, but thought I'd share. I haven't got a chance to try it yet, but you might want to check out electron-fetch: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch